Expected Number of Steps To Reach 0 in Circle
You are in a circle with 100 points labelled 0 - 99 clockwise. You start at 1 and can move left or right with equal probability. What is the expected time to reach $0$?
I attempted this by setting up a Markov chain recursive formula for the expectation at each point. For example: $E_i$ designates the expected number of steps to reach $0$ from point $i$. Hence, the first couple equations are:
$E_1 = \frac{1}{2} \times (1) + \frac{1}{2} \times (E_2 + 1) $
$E_2 = \frac{1}{2} \times (E_1 + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \times (E_3 + 1) $
You can expand this so on until point 99. However, I am having a hard time evaluating this.
Any advice?

What happens if you start with only three states: $0,1,2$ or only four states: $0,1,2,3$? A pattern should emerge pretty quickly but may differ if the total number of states is odd/even.

$$E_1-E_2/2=1$$
$$-E_1/2+E_2-E_3/2=1$$
$$-E_2/2+E_3-E_4/2=1$$
$$\dots$$
$$-E_{97}/2+E_{98}-E_{99}/2=1$$
$$-E_{98}/2+E_{99}=1$$
Adding the $99$ equations together gives $E_1/2+E_{99}/2=99$. By symmetry $E_1=E_{99}$, and so $E_1=99$.
